# C# IList.Where() equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, c#, list, lambda

How can I do this code of C# in Java?

```
public IEnumerable<Cliente> FiltroPorLocalidad(IList<Cliente> clientes)
     {
         return clientes.Where(c => c.Saldo < 0);
     }
```

Is there an equivalent to IList.Where() in Java?

Comment: Look up lambda expressions (available in Java 8) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: I'm not sure what the C# methods do here, but if my guess is correct, you probably want to look into [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/), in particular the `filter` method.

Comment: Thanks @ergonaut. But I want a IList.Where() equivalent in Java.
I think lambda expression is not the problem here.

Comment: @ajb It filters the elements in list "Clientes" when his property "Saldo" is lower than 0. It would be similar to: "SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE SALDO < 0".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The streams api is the analog here:

```
myList.stream().filter(s -> s.Saldo < 0)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks!
That's all for now.
Note: Best answer after six minutes.

Comment: I think he wanted to _return_ a list of the elements that pass the filter, not print them.  Could you edit your answer and show that?  It would be informative, since it would involve a collector.

Comment: I will. I was killing time with my cell phone, will fix it up.